# How can i get inside every object in a nested object structure?

Tags: javascript

I have an object `obj1` with another object inside `obj2`.

`obj2` is structured in the same way as `obj1` so there will be another object inside it.

Let's say that I have 20 of these and I'm trying to get inside each one of them to get some data.

Is there a way to create a loop that goes inside an obj as soon as it sees it?

I tried doing this but with no luck.

```js
var location;
for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
  var type = typeof value;
  var array = Array.isArray(value);
  if (typeof value === "object" && array === false && value) {
    location = key;
    for (var [a, b] of Object.entries(object[location])) {
      /*this is where I'm stuck, the location variable doesn't update with
      the 'path' of every object*/
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's your expected output? What do you wanna achieve with this? Maybe there's a simpler way of doing it.

Comment: Agree with Vishnudev, to help you we really need to see what the original object looks like and what you are trying to get from it.  On the surface it does look like you need a recursive function as suggested by Bulent but more detail will help us be more accurate and informative

Comment: The expected output would be to print in an HTML page the objects using an `ul` `li` list, so I didn't know how to get in all the objects and how to put them in a list giving them some sort of indentation.
```js
<ul>
  <li>obj1</li>
  <ul>
    <li>obj2</li>
    <ul>
      <li>obj3</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</ul>;
```
I did the first part and now I don't know how to indent the list :c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function that loop on one level. Check values for objects. If you find one, recall the same function.

```
function createLoop(obj) {
  for (const key in obj) {
     if (typeof obj[key] == "object") {
        createLoop(obj[key])
     } else {
       // do your stuff
     }
  }
}
```